# How can i pass my tests directly to nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, c89

I want to run C90 tests in NUnit. I have written a short adapter that actually works, but i want to get rid of writing that adapter and instead make a tool that opens nunit and passes in loadable data so that nunit can run the tests.

I spare you the codeload i wrote so far and just summarize its usage:

I wrtie my C90 tests as callable dll functions with annotations above them like comments. Example /*TEST*/. As of now the test returns 0 or 1 for pas fail information.
A C# Pathinspector inspects all *.c files for annotations and extracts the loadinformation.
A C# Executer manages the execution of the tests and returns PASS/FAIL information.

What i want to do instead of my Executer is to create either the Launchinformation for NUnit and pass that into a freshly created gui, or create C# code to pass into the freshly created gui.

I know how to create an NUnit gui runner, but i dont know how to pass information into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nunit source](http://nunit.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.4.7plus-pdfsg/) is online available, however it uses a lot of singletons during initialisation so i would argue against it.

One way could be to actually write and compile cs files and pass those compiled into nunit.

The best approach seems to be writing an xUnit compliant framework from scratch.